# java code is not compiling, neither giving any error

Tags: java

I'm learning java. What is wrong in this code. I tried but it is not working. Neither giving any error. I'm stuck here. What should I do?
**If you can, please give similar code that can work**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /*we will make a game in which we try to get same number on all of our dice. And count how much tries it take to match the dice.
        */

        int a = keepRolling();
        System.out.println(a);

    }

    //creating dice function first
    public static int rollDice() {
        double randomNumber = Math.random();
        randomNumber = randomNumber * 6;
        int randomAccurate = (int) randomNumber;
        randomAccurate = randomAccurate + 1;
        return randomAccurate;

    }


    public static int keepRolling() {
        int roll1 = rollDice();
        int roll2 = rollDice();
        int count = 1; //once it is already rolled when the function was called
        while (roll1 != roll2) {
            int roll1 = rollDice();
            int roll2 = rollDice();
            count = count + 1;
        }
        return count;
    }

}
```

Comment: All the answers so far tell what's wrong with the code and why it does not compile. But none could explain why you do not get any error messages: the compiler should scream very loud about the re-declaration of roll1 and roll2, and THAT is an error message!! So when you do not get anything, please provide the command(s) that you use to compile!!

Comment: I don't have working pc. I'm using android app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has a slight mistake and upon resolving it, it will be working fine.
You are redeclaring roll1 and roll2 in keepRolling() while loop which assigns different memory space during each iteration.

---

The working code:

```
    public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /*we will make a game in which we try to get same number on all of our dice. And count how much tries it take to match the dice.
        */

        int a = keepRolling();
        System.out.println(a);

    }

    //creating dice function first
    public static int rollDice() {
        double randomNumber = Math.random();
        randomNumber = randomNumber * 6;
        int randomAccurate = (int) randomNumber;
        randomAccurate = randomAccurate + 1;
        return randomAccurate;

    }


    public static int keepRolling() {
        int roll1 = rollDice();
        int roll2 = rollDice();
        int count = 1; //once it is already rolled when the function was called
        while (roll1 != roll2) {


             roll1 = rollDice();// No int declaration again
             roll2 = rollDice(); // No int declaration again

            count = count + 1;
        }
        return count;
    }

}
```

Comment: You are welcome @shippingyard.And to find out the reason why your compiler is not displaying the error messages can you tell about the IDE, JDK, and libraries you are using. If possible, tell the compilation commands too.

Comment: I'm using android app. Don't have pc. 

Comment: There you go. Your coding skills are special then.

Comment: Please give me +1 (Up arrow on left of my answer) if you have accepted my answer. Thanks.

Comment: I don't have voting privileges yet. Reputation is low.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not compilable. You have declared roll1 and roll2 twice in keepRolling method.

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /*we will make a game in which we try to get same number on all of our dice. And count how much tries it take to match the dice.
         */
        int a = keepRolling();
        System.out.println(a);
    }

    //creating dice function first
    public static int rollDice() {
        double randomNumber = Math.random();
        randomNumber = randomNumber * 6;
        int randomAccurate = (int) randomNumber;
        randomAccurate = randomAccurate + 1;
        return randomAccurate;

    }

    public static int keepRolling() {
        int roll1 = rollDice();
        int roll2 = rollDice();
        int count = 1; //once it is already rolled when the function was called
        while (roll1 != roll2) {
             roll1 = rollDice();
             roll2 = rollDice();
            count = count + 1;
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Now my code is working. You people are awesome

Answer (score 0):

Why are you re-declaring variable with same name inside your `while` loop?

```
    while (roll1 != roll2) {
        int roll1 = rollDice();
        int roll2 = rollDice();
        count = count + 1;
    }
```

Either rename them or remove second declaration of `int`

Comment: I am learning java. So I made this mistake.

Answer (score 0):

you have defined more than once  `roll1`and `roll2`in while loop

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate local variable  renamed roll1 and roll2

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /*we will make a game in which we try to get same number on all of our dice. And count how much tries it take to match the dice.
        */

        int a = keepRolling();
        System.out.println(a);

    }

    //creating dice function first
    public static int rollDice() {
        double randomNumber = Math.random();
        randomNumber = randomNumber * 6;
        int randomAccurate = (int) randomNumber;
        randomAccurate = randomAccurate + 1;
        return randomAccurate;

    }


    public static int keepRolling() {
        int roll1 = rollDice();
        int roll2 = rollDice();
        int count = 1; //once it is already rolled when the function was called
        while (roll1 != roll2) {
            int roll3 = rollDice();
            int roll4 = rollDice();
            count = count + 1;
        }
        return count;
    }

}
```

Comment: @shippingyard did your issue got resolved? if so accept the answer and +1 to post.

Comment: @shippingyard You did accept my answer and +1 to post.

Comment: @shippingyard https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: I don't have voting privilege yet. Sorry sir.

Comment: @shippingyard fine.

Answer (score 0):

You declared your variables twice in the same method. just replace your loop with this one

```
    while (roll1 != roll2) {
        roll1 = rollDice();  //remove the declarations
        roll2 = rollDice();
        count = count + 1;
    }
```

Comment: I'm so dumb.

Comment: Not at all. Mistakes like this are part of the learning process. You'll make a lot more mistakes before you become a master. Even then, you'll still make more mistakes.